# Как в цикле foreach в Qt пропустить первые два элемента?

Tags: qt, c++, foreach

```
QList<T> list;

foreach( T item, list )
{ 
....
}
```

То есть чтобы итерация начиналась с третьего элемента list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может, по старинке?

```
int k=0;
foreach( T item, list )
{ 
   k++;
   if(k<2) continue;
   ....
}
```

Хотя уверен, что сейчас придут люди и начнут рассуждать, что это противоречит MISRA, и будут правы. Если уж понадобилось работать с куском списка, то foreach уже не совсем подходит. Тогда уж лучше либо делать простой for и начинать его с 2, либо использовать итераторы с while:

```
QListIterator<int> iter(List);
iter.next();
iter.next();
while(iter.hasNext())
{
    ...
    iter.next();
}
```

Comment: с Range-based for loop также само?

Comment: Не понял вопроса.

Comment: @aknew, вообщем делаю рекурсивный обход по папкам и вот часть кода :  
      
    QDir mDir(path);
    QString buffer;
    for(QFileInfo temp : mDir.entryInfoList())
    {
        if(temp.fileName() == "." || temp.fileName() == "..")
            continue;

Вот этот пропуск двух элементов мне не совсем нравится, хотелось бы сразу цикл начинать минуя их. Вообщем привык в STL итераторах просто .begin()+2 делать, к примеру.

Comment: Вот это важно. Потому как "пропустить первые два элемента" ещё ничего не гарантирует. Можно пропустить и другие каталоги.

Правильный способ - это передать флажок QDir::NoDotAndDotDot в entryInfoList.

Comment: +1, тем более что я только что ради интереса попробовал и легко создал файлик ". test" в маке и... у меня стал третьим.

Comment: @KoVadim, полностью будет выглядеть так `.entryInfoList(QDir::NoDotAndDotDot | QDir::Dirs | QDir::Files)` ?

Comment: Вначале выставляется фильтр:

    mDir.setFilter(QDir::Dirs | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot);
    mDir.entryInfoList();

Answer (score 3):

Нужно в вести дополнительную переменную счетчик:

```
int i = 0;

foreach (){
i++;
if (i < 2)
   continue;
..ваш код..
}
```

Извините, не уверен в правильности (работает ли forech с оператором continue). Код на коленке выдумал.

Comment: Думал о подобном, но хотелось узнать о стандартных решениях.

Comment: Это и есть стандлартное.

Comment: делать подобное в foreach - плохой тон. В некоторых случаях порядок появления элементов не специфицирована.